# Unable to parse json string using python load or loads

Tags: python, json

I am a beginner with python. I am reading from an aerospike db, like this -

```
(key, metadata, record) = client.get(key)
print('aero ')
aerojson = json.load(record)
print(record)
```

Output is -

```
{'expiresIn': 1535873246092}
```

I am trying to parse the result set (so as to read expiresIn attribute), but am getting following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sandeepan-oauth_token_cache_random_sanity.py", line 29, in <module>
    aerojson = json.load(record)
  File "/root/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 287, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

If I change to json.loads(), I get -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sandeepan-oauth_token_cache_random_sanity.py", line 29, in <module>
    aerojson = json.loads(record)
  File "/root/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/root/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Please suggest proper documentation with examples.

Comment: You already did parse the JSON string and turned it into a dictionary. I'm not sure what you intend `read()` to do, just access the value by key. `aerojson['expiresIn']`. What is `fp`?

Comment: Ok, got it, I was trying to access using record.expiresIn. It worked with record['expiresIn']. Coming from different programming conventions :/